# Resetting textfield by clicking an image

Tags: jquery, html, textfield

I have an image that if clicked, the other div will opacity to 0 by using jquery. i want also that if the image is clicked, i will  reset the textfield.

here is my code.

```
<div id=loginExit>
    <img class='loginEXIT' src='Site_Images/close.png'>
</div>
<div id=loginForm>
    <div class=formC>
        <form name='loginForm' action='loginC.php' method='post'>
            <font face='Verdana' color=#d6d5d0 size=2>
                Email Address: &nbsp;
                <input type=text name='eadd' id=eaddtf style='width:150px;height:20px;border:1px solid #37749e;margin-bottom:5px;'>
               <br>
               Password: &nbsp;
               <input type=password name='pass' style='width:150px;height:20px;border:1px solid #37749e;margin-bottom:5px;'>
               <br>
               <input type=submit value='Login' class='login2' name=Submit style='cursor: pointer;text-decoration:none;font-size:14px; background-color:#46ae18; border:2px solid #58e01b;width:100px;'>
            </font>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class=clear></div>
</div>


$('.loginEXIT').click(function($event){
    $('#eaddtf').val('');
    $('#login').animate({opacity:0.0},'slow')
    $('#login').animate({left:-100000},'fast')
});
```

i want to reset the textfield of `input#eaddtf`. how can i?

Comment: @Deepu, $event is the event object....

Comment: still not working. it is only set opacity to 0 then go to left.. but not resetting the textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reset works for me, but you forgot to put the id in the login button

```
<input type=submit value='Login' class='login2' id="login" name=Submit style='cursor: pointer;text-decoration:none;font-size:14px; background-color:#46ae18; border:2px solid #58e01b;width:100px;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I have no idea why your solution is not working) :

```
$(document).on('click', '.loginEXIT', function() {
    $('#eaddtf').val('');
    $('#login').animate({opacity:0.0},'slow')
    $('#login').animate({left:-100000},'fast')
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't need `.on()`, as the DOM isn't dynamically generated.